# Laravel 5 - Implement Flash Messages with example not working

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, flash-message

I'm following this post here http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-implement-flash-messages-with-exampleexample.html, and in **Step 3: use flash messages with redirect** I've changed it so it calls the following method in my HomeController.php file:

```
public function index(Request $request) {
        return view("home")->with("info", "Please note that although Transport for South Africa is updated regularly, the site is still in BETA, and I'm hoping to have it complete by the 1st January 2018.");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in examples, you have to perform redirect to use flash messages (eg. with `back()` or `redirect()` helpers).

They are visible on the next request, not current one.

Comment: Howzit @Elon Than so how would I create a flash message on the current request, or should I just create the info message in my home.blade.php landing page, and use flash messages for redirects?

Comment: @TimothyKruger there is not need to use flash message if you just want to show it on the current request. Instead you can just display normal message, as you said.

Comment: Great thanks for the update and speedy response @Elon Than.